# UnboundLocalError while using Django Querysets

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement the following Django Queryset in my webapp:

```
from django.db.models import When, Case, Value, Sum, IntegerField, F
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from hr.models import *

def mobile_recharge(request):
    S=['0']
    T=['1']
    B=['A','B','C']
    db_obj1=BillsPayment.objects.using('MBDB').all()
    db_obj2=BillsService.objects.using('MBDB').all()
    while db_obj1.values('BILLER_ID')==db_obj2.values('BILLS_SERVICE_CODE') and db_obj2.values('BILLS_TYPE')=='3':
        data = db_obj1.annotate(
                            Transaction_type=F('BILLER_ID'),
                            Success=Sum(Case(
                                When(ERROR_CODE__in=S, then=Value(1)),
                                default=Value(0),
                                output_field=IntegerField()
                            )),
                            Technical_declines=Sum(Case(
                                When(ERROR_CODE__in=T, then=Value(1)),
                                default=Value(0),
                                output_field=IntegerField()
                            )),
                            Business_declines=Sum(Case(
                                When(ERROR_CODE__like='B',then=Value(1)),
                                When(ERROR_CODE__in=B, then=Value(1)),
                                When(ERROR_CODE__isnull=True, then=Value(1)),
                                default=Value(0),
                                output_field=IntegerField()
                            ))
                        ).order_by(Transaction_type)

    return render(request,'hr/test.html',{'model':data})
```

Which is supposed to execute the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT 'MOB' AS TYPE,
       SUM(case when BP.ERROR_CODE in ('0')
           then 1 else 0 end) SUCCESS,
       SUM(case when BP.ERROR_CODE in ('1')
           then 1 else 0 end) TECHNICAL_DECLINES,
       SUM(case when (BP.ERROR_CODE LIKE '%ERR%' OR BP.ERROR_CODE in ('A','B','C') or BP.ERROR_CODE is null )
           then 1 else 0 end) BUSINESS_DECLINES
FROM BP,BS
WHERE BP.BILLER_ID=BS.BILLS_CODE
AND BS.BILLS_TYPE='3';
```

When I run the server using the `python manage.py runserver` command however the browser is giving the UnboundLocalError:

[image]

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options what can you do in order to let this thing work. The error message says it clearly, that you are acctually accessing a variable that does not exist. In other words, you need to make sure its defined.

If personally do not understand, why did you put a `while` in there, but if you really do not need that `while` there, you can just put the return right after the data inicialization.

```
 while db_obj1.values('BILLER_ID')==db_obj2.values('BILLS_SERVICE_CODE') and db_obj2.values('BILLS_TYPE')=='3':
  # ^ this should be if, if you want to just return the first data

        data = db_obj1.annotate(
               ...
        ).order_by(Transaction_type)

        return render(request,'hr/test.html',{'model':data})
```

or if you really need that while to be there (for any reason in particular) then

```
data = None # <- add this line before while
while db_obj1.values('BILLER_ID')==db_obj2.values('BILLS_SERVICE_CODE') and db_obj2.values('BILLS_TYPE')=='3':
        data = db_obj1.annotate(
                            ...
                        ).order_by(Transaction_type)

return render(request,'hr/test.html',{'model':data})
```

Altho you need to do a few more stuff in HTML because of this (you will probably not want to see a blank spaces / errors where the text was supposed to be :)

Answer (score 1):

As said in the error you are referencing the variable data before assigning it, to solve this add the return statement in the while loop, or initialize the data variable before referencing it.

```
def mobile_recharge(request):
    S=['0']
    T=['1']
    data = None #initilized data with null
    ...

    while db_obj1.values('BILLER_ID')==db_obj2.values('BILLS_SERVICE_CODE') and db_obj2.values('BILLS_TYPE')=='3':

        data = db_obj1.annotate(
               Transaction_type=F('BILLER_ID'),
               Success=Sum(Case(
               ....
                ))
        ).order_by(Transaction_type)

        return render(request,'hr/test.html',{'model':data}) # return inside the while loop

    return render(request,'hr/test.html',{'model':data}) # return null if not match found
```